# Can we use more than one $rootScope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app Im using two `$rootScope` in the controller. One `$rootScope` is inside the function and another one is outside the function. Is it possible to use two `$rootScope` inside the controller and also when I use the `$rootScope` declared inside the function Im getting error stating that particular `$rootScope` is not declared. How to access the second `$rootScope` outside the function. So that I can perform splice action on it. Please do help to solve this. Thank you. :)

My Controller:

```
serviceApp.controller('carBrand',['$scope','carRepository','$rootScope','$state', function ($scope, carRepository, $rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.carSelect = carRepository.data;    //First rootScope
  $scope.newCarList = [];
  $scope.selectItem = function (key) {

     $rootScope.selectInput=key;         //second rootScope
    $state.go('app.carEdit',{object:key}); 
    return(key);
  }
```

Comment: There is only one `$rootScope` and you can access it wherever you like inside the controller.

Comment: @Evilzebra I have commented stating the First and Second rootScope in my controller.

Comment: You should be using a service, not $rootScope for sharing data across the app

Comment: using `$rootScope` at all is generally a code smell;  In this case, it's even more so, since you appear to be asking an [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) in response to an error.  Instead of asking about your error (Why `$rootScope` isn't declared), you are asking about a potential solution (accessing more than one `$rootScope`).  The fact that there aren't *really* two `$rootScope` objects only confuses your question, since the question isn't about "more than one `$rootScope`" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one `$rootScope`, it can be access everywhere injecting it in your controller.

If you want to share data between controllers, what you need to use is a service and inject it in the same way you inject `$rootScope`.